# Bypass Cloudflare-protected page and get html source in Java

Tags: java, html, cloudflare

I am trying to get the html page source of some websites that are cloudflare-protected and you see this message for 5 seconds:

> Checking your browser before accessing cloudbet.com.
>   This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.
>   Please allow up to 5 seconds…

I saw this:
https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape which claims to solve this problem, but I did not manage to reproduce this in Java.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232259/accessing-webpage-with-cloudflare-protection. Solution suggested there: contact the site owner to get whitelisted

Comment: I know it is, but whitlisting is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to reproduce the source code your mentioned but after connecting to the page which is checking the browser it does not redirect to the actual site I want to load. It always returns the same 503 error which was returned after the first connection.

I'll try to solve this problem and will post a solution as soon as it's working.